# Installing Hadoop2.7.0 on Windows7

Tags: windows, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop on Windows7 and I am getting some maven error. I am following this link for Hadoop installation
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os.

I am getting error on the (g). step of the link above. I am not able to attach the image. But I have written what the error says below.

I get error when I try to run this command:

```
mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

and the error is:

---

> The requested profile "dist" could not be activated because it does not exist.

The requested profile "native-win" could not be activated because it does not exist.

The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory. Please verify you invoked Maven from correct directory.

---

Can someone please help me with this error.